# Apache Nutch 2.3 and MySQL

Tags: mysql, nutch

Is there anyone who tried working with Apache Nutch 2.3 and MySQL? There are some people who say that Nutch 2.3 can no longer work with MySQL, but looking at the components in ivy.xml, MySQL is still in the list of possible dependencies. So, I did that as I would in the older Apache 2.x releases. Here's my ivy.xml (part of the gora artifacts):

```
<!--================-->
<!-- Gora artifacts -->
<!--================-->
<!-- N.B. To use Gora SNAPSHOT's merely replace the 'ref' value with the SNAPSHOT version 
and add changing="true" alongside the dependency declaration. An example has been
provided for the gora-core dependency as below -->
<dependency org="org.apache.gora" name="gora-core" rev="0.2.1" conf="*->default"/>

<!-- Uncomment this to use SQL as Gora backend. It should be noted that the 
gora-sql 0.1.1-incubating artifact is NOT compatable with gora-core 0.3. Users should 
downgrade to gora-core 0.2.1 in order to use SQL as a backend. -->

<dependency org="org.apache.gora" name="gora-sql" rev="0.1.1-incubating" conf="*->default" />
<!-- Uncomment this to use MySQL as database with SQL as Gora store. -->

<dependency org="mysql" name="mysql-connector-java" rev="5.1.18" conf="*->default"/>
```

Using ant runtime on this produces an error that points to line 101 of build.xml, saying

```
deprecation="${javac.deprecation}">
```

Does anyone have a workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, Nutch doesn't care the database underneath, Nutch works with the crawling database via Gora. Therefore, if Gora supports the database (MySQL, HBase, Cassandra), Nutch can crawl and put the content to the database. Please check gora and mysql version to fix the error in your case. You can follow this guide: http://www.solutions.asia/2013/06/installing-nutch-22-with-mysql-to.html.